# How do I stop users circumventing payment?

Tags: php, cookies, paypal

I have a site that uses paypal to collect payments for electronically displayed data. Variables can't be passed with the URL through paypal (or I can't get them to work) so I have used cookies to pass the item number. However, a crafty user could, after the cookie writing part, enter the paypal redirect URL directly into the address bar and get the e-data for free. Bypassing paypal. How can I get around this?

Here is some of the code. You will see I have tried to make it difficult for the user by passing straight through the cookie writing (pre_contact.php) and the paypal redirect URL (step.php).

```
//pre_contact.php
<?PHP
global $id;
setcookie("property", $id, time()+1800);
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"0; URL=contact.php\">";
?>

//contact.php - paypal pay button
echo "<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_s-xclick'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hosted_button_id' value='156320'>";
echo "<input type='image'
src='https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' 
alt='Click to pay'>";
echo "<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif'  width='1' height='1'>";
echo "</form>";

//step.php - paypal redirect on successful payment
<?PHP
require("generate_url.php");
?>

//generate_url.php - This generates a unique URL so the info can only be accessed once
<?PHP
if (eregi("generate_url.php", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) {
Header("Location: index.php"); die();
}
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(),1));
setcookie("token", $token, time()+4);
$cwd = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/"));
Header("Location: $cwd/get_file.php?q=$token"); die();
?>

//get_file.php - displays the file after payment
$qtoken = $_GET['q'];
if ($qtoken===$_COOKIE["token"]){
$id=$_COOKIE["property"];
DISPLAY FILE HERE!!
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

What your probably looking for is called Paypal IPN (Instant payment notification).. basically someone buys a product from you.. Paypal POSTS data to a script/url that you specify (only you and them know it).. Then what you do is post back data to paypal to confirm that the post they sent is real and not simulated/faked by someone..  At this point you know the transaction is valid.

Once you get notified of a valid payment, you can do something like send a download url via email, or wrap all that into a small login/password system using something simple like HTACCESS auth, and you've good to go.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Dreamwerx. As per my answer to Mark above it's too long winded and slows the process to the point I would lose sales. I'm thinking along the lines of tracking the URL history?

Comment: You either need to fix the problem correctly once, or keep working around with with hack fixes like URL tracking, etc. that people will eventually be able to circumvent.  Not fixing the problem correctly can potentially lose you more sales in fraud.  IPN is definately the way to go.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I've just been looking at it. Seems very complicated but does look like you can fully automate it which would be fine. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I use PayPal IPN for my sales system and it works perfectly. The notifications come within seconds of payment and then I just email the person the key. Has worked great since I started using it.

Comment: I agree.  I use IPN on a gaming website to track user donations.  Payments are verified instantly and users can't circumvent it.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you're going to be able to do what you want in a single step with the approach you're taking because your code has no way of knowing if the transaction actually finished successfully or not.

I think the only way the above approach will work is if you don't automatically send them over to the file they paid for.

Instead, they have to wait for you to verify their transaction through Paypal and then email them a download link.

---

It could probably all be done automatically using the [Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/).  I'm not that familiar with the Paypal API but it should work something like this.

1. User decides to buy something from you
2. You start a transaction which sends the user over to Paypal and, presumably, generates some sort of transaction id.
3. The user pays (or decides to cancel and/or not pay)
4. The user comes back to your site
5. You take the transaction id and verify that the payment was successful
6. If the payment was successful, give the user the stuff they paid for.

---

### [Paypal API Reference](https://www.paypal.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_api-reference.html)

Comment: Thanks Mark. That seems a very long winded way around it and quite labour intensive. I would prefer to lose a few sales to crafty users than tie someone up verifying payments. Can I somehow reject the user if they haven't come from paypal? I can't use CURL or REFERER as my host has them turned off.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of information about PayPal IPN in other questions, start with [Setting up Paypal to connect to script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115822/setting-up-paypal-to-connect-to-script)